# How do I position the icon to the right of the heading?

Tags: html, css

I would like the layout to look as so, but also be responsive (so that the heading + paragraph both stay positioned to the left of the icon).

[image]

CSS:

```
.feature {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.circle {
  height: 2.5rem;
  width: 2.5rem;
  background-color: #64beeb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.icon {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  color: #fff;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="feature">
  <div class="text text-right">
    <p class="h2">Diversity of Content</p>
    <p class="descrip">Dive deep and share themed content across various topics based on your audience</p>
  </div>
  <div class="circle text-center">
    <i class="icon ion-android-bulb"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](https://codepen.io/minacosentino/full/BwxPex)

Comment: You could remove `float: right;` from the `.circle` and set the parent (`.feature`) to `display: flex;`, which automatically positions/resizes child items to fit side-by-side. *(You may also need to put `flex-shrink: 0` on the `.circle` to make sure that it doesn't "shrink to fit".)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `flexbox`. You can add `display: flex` to the container (`.feature`). Add `flex: 1` to the text. To create some space around the icon you can use a `margin` value you find suitable.

```css
.feature {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  /* for demo */
  text-align: right;
  display: flex;
}

.text {
  flex: 1;
}

.circle {
  height: 2.5rem;
  width: 2.5rem;
  background-color: #64beeb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.icon {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="feature">
  <div class="text text-right">
    <p class="h2">Diversity of Content</p>
    <p class="descrip">Dive deep and share themed content across various topics based on your audience</p>
  </div>
  <div class="circle text-center">
    <i class="icon ion-android-bulb"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought this one was simpler / required less edits. Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

add this to `.circle` and remove `float:right;` Then it will be absolutely positioned from the parent `relative` container.

```
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
```

```css
.feature {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  height: 2.5rem;
  width: 2.5rem;
  background-color: #64beeb;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.icon {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="feature">
  <div class="text text-right">
    <p class="h2">Diversity of Content</p>
    <p class="descrip">Dive deep and share themed content across various topics based on your audience</p>
  </div>
  <div class="circle text-center">
    <i class="icon ion-android-bulb"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

And you could add `padding-right: 50px;` to `.feature` so the icon (blueih circle) will not be over text. See here https://jsfiddle.net/ymzofeph/

Answer (score 0):

```
         <div class="feature">
            <div class="circle text-center">
                <i class="icon ion-android-bulb"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="text text-right">
                <p class="h2">Diversity of Content</p>
                <p class="descrip">Dive deep and share themed content across various topics based on your audience</p>
              </div>
         </div>
         <style>
          .circle{
             float:right;
             width:40px;
             height:40px;
             margin:0 0 0 20px;
          }
          .text{
             overflow:hidden;
          }
         </style>
```

Comment: Vote if the answer is helpful for you
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put the `float:right` `div` before the `.text-right` `div`. Then add `padding-right:2.5rem;` to the `.text-right` `div`.

[Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jGJzEK)